# JBOD on cassandra issue

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, scylla

I have 3 node cassandra cluster with JBOD configuration. I have 4 disk for data /data1, /data2, /data3, /data4. Now, we are facing space issue on disk on nodes frequently. Currently /data1 is full (100%) and other disk /data2(26%),/data3(34%), data4(17%) utilised on node 1 and other nodes have sufficient space on all disks.

1)So,my question is if any requests will come on cassandra cluster and data will go to /data1 on node1 what will happen? Is request fail? or cassandra will manage and will write to the other disk which are having space ?

2) JBOD is useful in cassandra except disk disaster recovery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The data should be distributing evenly. Did you add those disks one at a time or all at once?

You can read up more about how this works on Anthony Grasso's article at http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/08/22/the-fine-print-when-using-multiple-data-directories.html

His suggestion and mine is that if you want to use many disks/data dirs, try combining them with [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) or [ZFS](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs.html)

Comment: Thanks Rahul but data is not distributing as I mentioned in my question. Yes, all disk added during the installation only. But my question is above 2 what I described.

Comment: Then you may have wide partitions on some data , and these wide partitions have to be clumped together in SSTables for obvious reasons. You may want to see how big your partitions are and see if there are some really large ones.

Comment: This is the reason for data not evenly distributing right? @ Rahul, what about my above 2 questions?

Comment: While new data whether by stream or by new inserts , it will go to different drives, but as long as it thinks the old SSTables are still there, it will continue going to disk1

Comment: @Thanks Rahul for your time. So cassandra will manage automatically if /data1 will full(100%) then it will write the data on other disk and my query will not fail. As per my understanding sstables are immutable then why cassandra will think about old sstables ?

Comment: On compaction, the redundant writes get "compacted" and all updates to a partition are moved to be next to each other. At that time older entries get cleaned out / garbage collected. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataMaintain.html

Comment: Okay, Is there any configurations where we can set the disk threshold  value for all disk using JBOD so that we can avoid these kind of issue and compaction and writes will happen smoothly?